# Laravel 5.5 model pivot table count

Tags: model, laravel-5.5, eloquent

I have 3 tables. `users`,`gallery` and `gallery_blog`.`gallery_blog` has `gallery_id` and `blog_id`.`gallery_blog` is a pivot table. `gallery` has `user_id` and `name`. `users` has `id`.One User has many gallery. One gallery has many blog.

I need a query to know how many blogs in a gallery along with gallery name of current user.

I wrote below query

```
use App\User as user_gallery;    
$galleries = user_gallery::find(Auth::user()->id)->gallery;
```

I have below code in `User` model.

```
public function gallery() {   
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Gallery');  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$galleries = Gallery::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->withCount('blogs')->get();
```

The `Gallery` class must have a `blogs()` relation.

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)